# Send Json POST as parameter to Fullcalendar

Tags: json, events, post, fullcalendar

Im developing a scheduler software application for room reservation...

im looking for a way to send a json file through a post ajax request using event method of full calendar:

here's what im doing:

```
<-Fullcalendar javascript-->

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: calview
      },
      editable: true,
      allDaySlot: false,
      eventLimit: true,
      selectable: true,
      selectHelper: true,
      eventSources:[
        {
            events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'events/GetEvents2.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  dataType: "json",
                  contentType: "application/json",
                  data: {
                      customValue: setcalendarfilters()
                  }
               });
            }
        }


      ],

});

<-Fullcalendar javascript-->
```

<-function to get loop all the selections as filters of the user  javascript-->

```
      function setcalendarfilters(){
               //this function returns :
    {
      seats:[
        id_location: 1,
        id_zone:1
        seats: [
          {
            id_spot: 1,
            id_spot: 2,
            id_spot: 3,
          }]
        ]
    }

}
```

<-function to get loop all the selections as filters of the user  javascript-->

After that, i need to send this json object as parameter to the request so my php catch it and use the vars as filters for my mysql query, but it keep sending it as url params like:

getevents2.php?id_location=1&......

NOTE: I cant use GET (at least is what i think) because the users can add as many filters as he wants dynamically for example:

```
{
  seats:
   {
    id_location: 1,
    id_zone:1
    seats: [
      {
        id_spot: 1,
        id_spot: 2,
        id_spot: 3,
      }]
    },
   {
    id_location: 8,
    id_zone:4
    seats: [
      {
        id_spot: 3,
      }]
    },   {
    id_location: 9,
    id_zone:1
    seats: [
      {
        id_spot: 15,
        id_spot: 26,
        id_spot: 33,
      }]
    }
}
```